# Macro Closes Itself Before Completion

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

The codes below are summarized: It is used to get the match information (score, bet rate, predictions) of the matches of that day from the match link entered in column A on the Sofascore site. He clicks on the matches in order, gets the information from the window that opens on the side, and moves on to the next match. It does this by clicking on the matches it finds with x.FindElementsByClass("kusmLq"), in order. But although I tried in different ways, after about 3 minutes and 45 seconds, the program ends no matter what game it is in. However, there are other matches below and the macro must continue. It doesn't always end in the same match, when I change the waiting times, it ends in another match, but the important thing is the time. He finishes after 3 minutes 45 seconds. Chrome closes and the information is written in excel. I don't understand why it auto-closes and the macro terminates. I may be making a mistake somewhere, I'm new and inexperienced in these matters. I would be glad if you help.:
Note: The classes in the page are loaded as the page goes down. It only detects the classes on the page it sees at that moment. That's why I slowly lowered the page with each click, but it didn't work.
Note 2 : The project is the excel selenium vba project.

```
Sub sofascore()

Dim x As New Selenium.ChromeDriver, i, j, sonsat, LastRow As Integer

x.SetProfile "C:\Users\Oğuzhan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
x.AddArgument ("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Oğuzhan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\System Profile")
x.Start "chrome", "https://www.sofascore.com/tr/"
x.Window.Maximize

x.Wait 4000
sonsat = Sheets("veri").Range("A350").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To sonsat
x.Get Range("A" & i).Value
x.Wait 1000
 
Dim clss As Selenium.WebElements
Dim cls As Selenium.WebElement
Set clss = x.FindElementsByClass("kusmLq")

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
j = LastRow + 1
x.Wait 500
For Each cls In clss
cls.Click
On Error Resume Next
x.Wait 2200
Range("B" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.gRrJCY > div.sc-hLBbgP.eVYvKu > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.eISiVT.bbcOkn > div:nth-child(1) > span").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("C" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.gRrJCY > div.sc-hLBbgP.eVYvKu > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.eISiVT.bbcOkn > div:nth-child(2) > span").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("N" & j) = Replace(x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dPIoqB > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.etIUTK > div:nth-child(1) > div > div").Text, "MS ", "")
Range("D" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dPIoqB > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.jxNKfs > div.sc-hLBbgP.dgRNvP > div:nth-child(2) > div > a:nth-child(1) > div > span").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("E" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dPIoqB > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.jxNKfs > div.sc-hLBbgP.dgRNvP > div:nth-child(2) > div > a:nth-child(2) > div > span").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("F" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dPIoqB > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.jxNKfs > div.sc-hLBbgP.dgRNvP > div:nth-child(2) > div > a:nth-child(3) > div > span").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("G" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dPIoqB > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.eUyyBS > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > span.sc-eDWCr.cyHYdu").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("H" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dPIoqB > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.eUyyBS > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > span.sc-eDWCr.gsyJvw").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("I" & j) = x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.fOCbiM.sc-cabffeca-2.fbSWpy > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dPIoqB > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.eUyyBS > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > span.sc-eDWCr.vGYDN").Text
On Error Resume Next
Range("J" & j).Value = Range("G" & j) + Range("H" & j) + Range("I" & j)
On Error Resume Next
Range("K" & j).Value = Range("G" & j) / Range("J" & j)
On Error Resume Next
Range("L" & j).Value = Range("H" & j) / Range("J" & j)
On Error Resume Next
Range("M" & j).Value = Range("I" & j) / Range("J" & j)
x.Wait 1000
j = j + 1
x.ExecuteScript "window.scrollBy(0,50);"
x.Wait 300
On Error Resume Next
Next

Next

End Sub
```

The classes in the page are loaded as the page goes down. It only detects the classes on the page it sees at that moment. That's why I slowly lowered the page with each click, but it didn't work.

Comment: Remove all the `On error resume next` they are hiding whatever the problem is (also, you don't need to repeat it, it stays in effect until you use `On error goto 0`)

Comment: Thank you for finding out about this. But when I remove 'on error resume next', the macro gets stuck on some elements and won't progress. There are some elements that are not available in every match. These are 3 pieces.

In the above codes Range("D" & j) , Range("E" & j) and Range("F" & j) =
Emotes are not available for every match, and macro stops when it comes to matches. What can I do for it. When it can't find this element, it works even if it writes 0 or X for D,E,F, but I don't know how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: When he can't find the values in D,E,F, he should move on to the next step, H, and click on the next match after completing it. If it cannot find D,E,F, it can either leave it blank or print 0 or X, it doesn't matter. The important thing for me is to complete the loop by continuing to click until the last link on the page.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge, but I think it is necessary to write a code like if the element exists or not. But I do not know how.

Comment: Even though I removed all on error resume nexts, there was no solution. Despite the clean code window, the chrome window still closes in the same place. I don't understand if there is something like a self-timer.

Comment: remove all `On Error Resume Next` and leave only one before in the conflicting ranges an put the `On Error Goto 0` after those to see if there is another Error

Comment: Thanks all. I can't solve problem.. I don't have no more hopes.